# health checks failing on GAE custom runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We're following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) to launch our django app using a custom runtime. Since this requires that our app handle the health checks, we added this line of code to urls.py:

```
url(r"/_ah/health", lambda r: HttpResponse()),
```

Alas, we're still getting a 502 error from the health checks. What are we doing wrong here?

**Edit**

I'm including some of our deployment files/commands

**Deployment command**
`gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml app_staging.yml`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

# Use python 3 version of GAE base image
LABEL python_version python3.5
RUN virtualenv --no-download /env -p python3.5
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Install all dependencies in requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app

# Run staging migrations then tests. Then run the gunicorn server
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD python manage.py migrate --settings app.settings.staging && \ 
    gunicorn -b :8080 app.wsgi
```

**app_staging.yml**

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$8080 app.wsgi

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: <CONNECTION>

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.90
  disk_size_gb: 10

liveness_check:
  path: '/_ah/health'
  timeout_sec: 4
  check_interval_sec: 30
  failure_threshold: 4
  success_threshold: 2
  initial_delay_sec: 3600

readiness_check:
  path: '/_ah/health'
  timeout_sec: 4
  check_interval_sec: 5
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 3600

env_variables:
  PROJECT_VARIABLES
```

**dispatch.yaml**

```
dispatch:
- url: "staging.app.io/*"
  service: frontend

- url: "staging-backend.app.io/*"
  service: default
```

Comment: Did you tried to set response status to 200 explicitly?

Comment: Do you mean like this `url(r"/_ah/health", lambda r: HttpResponse("OK", status=200)),`?

Comment: Yes. Did you also look inside App Engine logs? There are specific log called nginx.healt_check where health checks are logged. Check it out.

Comment: Yup, I've seen those entries. They're throwing 503 errors and really not sure why.

Comment: Do you using dispatch.yaml? Maybe dispatch rules somehow redirects you'r destinations, but it actually stupid reason. Okay. Can you post your app.yaml file?

Comment: Yup, we use dispatch.yaml. I was hopeful that was the problem but deploying without dispatch.yaml still throws a 404 and doesn't deploy. I edited my question to include the files. This is the setup that throws 404 errors.

Comment: FYI - we changed our urls.py to this and now we're getting a 301 error message:
`url(r'^_ah/health/', lambda r: HttpResponse("OK", status=200)),`
`url(r'^readiness_check/', lambda r: HttpResponse("OK", status=200)),`
`url(r'^liveness_check/', lambda r: HttpResponse("OK", status=200)),`

Comment: Did you run ```gcloud beta app update --split-health-checks --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]``` ? This is required to enable updated health checks. But, do you actually using benefits of spitted health checking? From you file I can see, that health checks points to the same route, and you don't actually differentiate readiness (for example maximum connections support checks) and liveness (nginx or docker or application direct responses). So, maybe you should just use legacy health checking mechanism, as time-tested approach for now?

Comment: Yep, I ran that command. I also split the paths to route to the liveness and readiness. When we switch back to legacy checks, it's the same problem. This is really weird now. In the same deployment, we got 200, 301, and 503 messages for our health checks

Comment: When you switched backed to legacy checks, did you also disabled it with --split-health-checks? Did you tried to ping you'r app on this route locally?

Comment: What is the command used to disable the updated health checks? I've run the same exact command before and unfortunately doesn't do much.

Comment: Ok, so we switched back to Legacy Checks with the snippet in our App.yaml file and were able to deploy and get 200 responses. Never ran a command to reverse the updated health checks though. Thanks for all the help!